# enable VM insights for a Log Analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to enable VM Insights for a log analytics workspace using arm template. Below is the template

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "VMISolutionDeployment",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "name": "VMInsights(Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace)",
        "workspaceResourceId": "/subscriptions/d6b4b525-b127-4ff9-8b45-8cec1f768475/resourceGroups/Sajith-LogAnalytics-Test/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace"
      },
      "plan": {
        "name": "VMInsights(Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace)",
        "product": "OMSGallery/VMInsights",
        "publisher": "Microsoft"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
      "location": "UK South",
      "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview"
    }
  ]
}
```

While trying to deploy, getting below error

```json
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "DeploymentFailed",
    "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"InvalidParameter\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The value supplied for property must not be null. Operation Id: '5c6045e36ab28c4b899737e9358b91b9'\",\r\n    \"target\": \"plan.promotionCode\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any insight to this error will be really helpful

Regards,
Sajith

Comment: As stated in the error message you need to specify the `plan.promotionCode` property.

Answer (score 0):

From the `ARM template` provided by you says that you have not declared  `promotionCode`  inside the  `plan` node.

And as suggested by the `@Thomas` it is clearly stated in the error message.

Here is the sample template which configures your Log Analytics workspace to support VM insights by enabling the solutions.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "WorkspaceResourceId": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Workspace Resource ID."
            }
        },
        "WorkspaceLocation": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Workspace Location."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "VMISolutionDeployment",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
                            "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
                            "location": "[parameters('WorkspaceLocation')]",
                            "name": "[concat('VMInsights', '(', split(parameters('WorkspaceResourceId'),'/')[8], ')')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "workspaceResourceId": "[parameters('WorkspaceResourceId')]"
                            },
                            "plan": {
                                "name": "[concat('VMInsights', '(', split(parameters('WorkspaceResourceId'),'/')[8], ')')]",
                                "product": "[concat('OMSGallery/', 'VMInsights')]",
                                "promotionCode": "",
                                "publisher": "Microsoft"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "subscriptionId": "[split(parameters('WorkspaceResourceId'),'/')[2]]",
            "resourceGroup": "[split(parameters('WorkspaceResourceId'),'/')[4]]"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

For more information you can refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-enable-resource-manager#resource-manager-templates)  which shows you creating of VM, VM insights and log analytics workspace.